# How to index to avoid full table scan?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

How can I index the following query to avoid the full table scan?

```
explain SELECT fld1, fld2 FROM tablename WHERE IdReceived > 0; 

+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablename        | ALL  |IdReceived _idx| NULL | NULL    | NULL | 99617 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

I have modified the query as bellow then also I can see row id2 (UNION) is going for full table scan.

```
explain SELECT fld1,fld2 FROM tablename WHERE IdReceived=1 UNION SELECT fld1,fld2 FROM tablename WHERE IdReceived>=1;
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table            | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | tablename | ref  | IdReceived _idx  | IdReceived _idx | 4       | const |  8865 |             | 
|  2 | UNION        | tablename | ALL  | IdReceived _idx  | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  | 99617 | Using where | 
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2>       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL  |  NULL |             | 
+----+--------------+------------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: Try to force statistic updates. It *has* the appropriate index. The query planner must determine it's better not to use it. (Also, what is the distribution of values in the IdRecieved column like?)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing the indexed column with the constant value,try to avoid that.

Refer here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

Also I suggest a non_clustered index on fld1,fld2 to make this query perform faster

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense; it would likely make sense *if* qualified with *why* a constant value might result in *not using the index*.

Comment: "Since you are comparing the indexed column with the constant value,the table sacn is must there." means that **all queries with constants will ignore indices**.

Comment: Which part? Be sure to include excerpts/quotes/accurate summaries of external resources.

Comment: That does not mean what you think it does. There is nothing there that says "constant folding forces table scans" -- because that would be dumb.

Comment: SELECT fld1,fld2 FROM tablename WHERE IdReceived=1 UNION SELECT fld1,fld2 FROM tablename FORCE INDEX(IdReceived _idx ) WHERE IdReceived>=1;  This will resolve the issue, But any disadvantage in using FORCE INDEX key word as the query is fired frequently ?

Comment: Cant you just use like this:SELECT fld1,fld2 FROM tablename FORCE INDEX(IdReceived _idx) WHERE IdReceived>=1.Why you need UNION?

Comment: check this- http://www.mysqldiary.com/the-battle-between-force-index-and-the-query-optimizer/